# duplicate and combine two dataframes pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, join

**Background**

I have two sample df's

Here is `df1`

```
import pandas as pd
l =  [list(['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'])]
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Letters': l})

df1
      Letters
 0  [ABC, DEF, GHI]
```

And `df2`

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Text' : ['Hi ', 
                                       'hey', 
                                       'hello ',
                                        'bye',
                                        'see ya'
                            ], 

                          'ID': [1,2,3, 4,5]
                         })
df2     
        ID Text
    0   1   Hi
    1   2   hey
    2   3   hello
    3   4   bye
    4   5   see ya
```

**Desired Output**

```
    ID Text  Letters
0   1   Hi     [ABC, DEF, GHI]
1   2   hey    [ABC, DEF, GHI]
2   3   hello  [ABC, DEF, GHI]
3   4   bye    [ABC, DEF, GHI]
4   5   see ya [ABC, DEF, GHI]
```

**Question**

How do I duplicate and combine `df1` with `df2` to get my desired output?

Comment: df2['letters'] = df['letters']?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do:

```
df2=df2.assign(**pd.concat([df1]*len(df2),ignore_index=True))
```

Or:

```
df2=df2.assign(Letters=np.resize(df1.to_numpy(),len(df2))) #df1.values for lower versions
```

---

```
     Text  P_ID          Letters
0     Hi      1  [ABC, DEF, GHI]
1     hey     2  [ABC, DEF, GHI]
2  hello      3  [ABC, DEF, GHI]
3     bye     4  [ABC, DEF, GHI]
4  see ya     5  [ABC, DEF, GHI]
```

Comment: Nice one with `pd.concat` :) +1

Answer (score 3):

Can also `broadcast_to`

```
df2['letters'] = np.broadcast_to(df1['Letters'], len(df2))
```

---

```
    Text    P_ID    letters
0   Hi      1       [ABC, DEF, GHI]
1   hey     2       [ABC, DEF, GHI]
2   hello   3       [ABC, DEF, GHI]
3   bye     4       [ABC, DEF, GHI]
4   see ya  5       [ABC, DEF, GHI]
```

Comment: aha, nice, thanks for introducing this :) any good read about `resize` v/s `broadcast` difference ?

Comment: @anky_91 Not sure about a good read but they're fundamentally different ;p `resize` will resize to the specified shape no matter what. It introduces copies of the values in the beginning of the array to its end to "fill" it until it reaches the shape. `broadcast` follows very strict [broadcasting rules](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)